# How to repaint your steering wheel emblem?

Tags: repair, paint, steering-wheel, paint-clearcoat, cosmetic

I have an older car with a chrome steering wheel emblem. The chrome has started to flake off and look unpleasant. Half the emblem is chrome and half is dull off-white plastic:
[image: similar to this picture but my car is a 2008 Mazda3]

**What is the easiest way to repaint the steering wheel emblem?**

I saw [a guide where he tries to spray paint the emblem but... the results are not so nice ... and there is lots of undesirable overspray on many pieces of the car](http://www.mazda3forums.com/149-interior-mods-technical-information-faqs-how-tos/333711-how-paint-your-steering-wheel-emblem-without-removing.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use a small paint brush and small 1-2 oz paint wells from your local hobby store (Instead of using spray paint in a small enclosed area... Like the example link I provided in the question):

- prep the surface

  - sand the emblem carefully with 1000 grit (taking care not to scratch the steering wheel part)
  - clean the surface of dust and oils --> use either soap and water or some solvent (Xylene or Klean-Strip's "PREP-ALL")
- apply blue masking tape
- cut out the emblem from the tape
- using a small paint brush, paint 1-3 coats of chrome or black
- followed by a 1-3 coats of clear coat

I would have preferred to replace the emblem but my car's make/model (2008 Mazda 3) steering wheel emblem has 7 pegs that go into the steering wheel plate and I'm not confident the emblem could be removed by itself.

Comment: Isn't that a Honda emblem? Also, you probably want to clean the emblem before painting with a ScotchBrite pad to buff it up a little, then with some PrepAll to clean up any residuals or oils. Otherwise, great instruction.

Comment: I have a Mazda but the photo I posted is for a Honda because that is what I found on Google images.

Comment: To get a chrome finish you need special paint. I know of 2 brands (form the scale modeling world) that supply a chrome paint: Alclad and Humbrol. Alclad requires some preparation (it needs a perfectly smooth undercoat) and has to be airbrushed. Humbrol's chrome paint has to be buffed out after application, and I haven't been able to brush paint their chrome paint either.

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit my post... Maybe I'll just go with non chrome paint? I don't want to do any air/spray painting.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to repaint the emblem is not to.  These can be purchased very cheaply (cheaper than you'd pay for paint and materials) on eBay, Amazon and other similar websites.

Comment: i did see that you can purchase steering wheel emblems and they looked cheap. but i'm not sure for my make/model (2008 mazda 3) that i can just pry up the old one. i might have to take off the cover over the airbag which may be difficult.

Comment: To paint it you'll want to remove it anyway.  They are usually just stuck / clipped on.

Answer (score 1):

I have been to Honda dealer they said the emblem on 2009 pilot steering wheel is attached to the air bag and cannot be switched out
I would have to replace the air bag 600. + dollars
I have googled decals, stickers etc nothing that will cover the H on my car
Painting seems the solution ( maybe silver nail polish )
I even asked the body repair shop that Honda uses no solution but to replace the air bag

Comment: thanks for the post! i sold my car a while ago :). i ended up just emphasizing all the good parts of the car and de-emphasizing that part of the car. the buyer i had didn't really notice fortunately (some people are less detail oriented).